# Azure function rapid scaling beyond 200 instances

Tags: azure-functions, autoscaling

I am working on a web project that includes image processing. I have it implemented as an azure function. However, I have some problems with scaling out.
The general gist is that the user sends a set of images for processing (set contains anything from 100-1000 images). The processing of each image can be performed in parallel. Each image processing request is sent as a separate event to the event grid. Then an event triggered function A creates a JSON blob that is then processed by blob triggered function B. Function A processing takes 1s while function B processing time is roughly 1 minute.

My problem is scaling out limits and speed of function B. Single execution of function B is around 1 minute what is expected. However, it takes about 15-20 minutes to process  1000 images, while the maximum number of instances is around 100.

Is there a way to force rapid scaling to match the number of instances of azure function to the number of images waiting for processing? For example, as I get 1000 processing requests, I immediately spin 500 instances.

Is there a way to go over the limit of 200 azure function instances in the consumption plan?

Is there another technology that you would advise to consider for this project to be able to scale out rapidly?

Comment: can you add context to the question around what sort of image processing you are doing, resizing, object detection etc?? to be able to recommend options

Comment: It is an object detection. The result is a simple JSON that is used further down the pipeline for some calculations.

Comment: What may also be important is that the main algorithm is written in c++ and delivered in custom dll that is executed by azure function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no way to go over the 200 limit, you can deploy multiple function apps to work around it with both functions running off of messages in a service bus queue.

Instead of Function B being a blob-triggered function, make it a service bus queue triggered function with [blob creation events sent to the queue via Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus).

Also, if you're functions are compute intensive, you could consider the [premium plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan) as well which might cut down on runtime.